# How do I refresh a HDFS path?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am runing a sparksession in jupyter notebook .

I would got error sometime on a dataframe which is initial by `spark.read.parquet(some_path)`  when files under that path have changed,  even if I cache the dataframe .

### For example

reading code is

```
sp = spark.read.parquet(TB.STORE_PRODUCT)
sp.cache()
```

sometimes, sp can't not be access anymore, complain :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3274.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 326.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 10.3 in stage 326.0 (TID 111818, dc38, executor 7): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://xxxx/data/dm/sales/store_product/part-00000-169428df-a9ee-431e-918b-75477c073d71-c000.snappy.parquet
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

### The problem

> 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' doesn't work, because

- I don't have a hive table, it is only a hdfs path

> Restart sparksession and read that path again can solve this problem , but

- I don't want to restart sparksession, it would waste much time

> One more

- execute `sp = spark.read.parquet(TB.STORE_PRODUCT)` again doesn't work , I can understand why, spark should scan the path again or there must be a option/setting to force it scan . Keep whole path location in memory is not smart .

> spark.read.parquet doesn't have a force scan option

```
Signature: spark.read.parquet(*paths)
Docstring:
Loads Parquet files, returning the result as a :class:`DataFrame`.

You can set the following Parquet-specific option(s) for reading Parquet files:
    * ``mergeSchema``: sets whether we should merge schemas collected from all                 Parquet part-files. This will override ``spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema``.                 The default value is specified in ``spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema``.

>>> df = spark.read.parquet('python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned')
>>> df.dtypes
[('name', 'string'), ('year', 'int'), ('month', 'int'), ('day', 'int')]

.. versionadded:: 1.4
Source:   
    @since(1.4)
    def parquet(self, *paths):
        """Loads Parquet files, returning the result as a :class:`DataFrame`.

        You can set the following Parquet-specific option(s) for reading Parquet files:
            * ``mergeSchema``: sets whether we should merge schemas collected from all \
                Parquet part-files. This will override ``spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema``. \
                The default value is specified in ``spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema``.

        >>> df = spark.read.parquet('python/test_support/sql/parquet_partitioned')
        >>> df.dtypes
        [('name', 'string'), ('year', 'int'), ('month', 'int'), ('day', 'int')]
        """
        return self._df(self._jreader.parquet(_to_seq(self._spark._sc, paths)))
File:      /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py
Type:      method
```

Is there a proper way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by `Dataframe.cache` .

I need clear that cache at first , then read again would solve the problem

code :

```
try:
    sp.unpersist()
except:
    pass
sp = spark.read.parquet(TB.STORE_PRODUCT)
sp.cache()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try two solutions

one is to unpersist the dataframe before reading everytime as suggested by @Mithril

or just create a temp view and trigger the refresh command

```
sp.createOrReplaceTempView('sp_table')
spark.sql('''REFRESH TABLE sp_table''')
df=spark.sql('''select * from sp_table''')
```